# How to change point data to polygon in osm

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-systems

Hi all i have an array of point object of OpenLayers called vertices[] as
vertices="POINT(78.40873715820317 17.400524043704443),
POINT(78.425388311768 17.38692766193279),
POINT(78.40238568725626 17.384142736159205)"

i want to change it in the polygon format with same coordinates as
vertices1[]= "POLYGON((78.40873715820317 17.400524043704443,78.425388311768 17.38692766193279,78.40238568725626 17.384142736159205,78.40873715820317 17.400524043704443))"
How can i convert it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
var vertices="POINT(78.40873715820317 17.400524043704443), POINT(78.425388311768 17.38692766193279), POINT(78.40238568725626 17.384142736159205)";

var vertices_array = vertices.split(',');

var sitePoints = [];

for (var i=0;i<vertices_array.length;i++)
{
    var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();

    var pointWKT = wkt.read(vertices_array[i]);

    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(pointWKT.geometry.x, pointWKT.geometry.y);

    sitePoints.push(point);
}

var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(sitePoints);

var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);

var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry,null);

var polygonWKT = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();

var output = polygonWKT.write(polygonFeature);

alert(output);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't just dump your code, explain your train of thought so we can better understand your answer. Thanks.